# Custom checkbox wont toggle with basic jQuery class add

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create custom styled radio and checkboxes (thus the extra CSS below), but the checkbox won't toggle when I click the label.  The radio buttons work fine clicking the label, but not the checkboxes UNLESS the link in the label is clicked - then it works.  The other odd thing is a click-n-drag on the text (like to highlight a word) will also toggle it, just not a simple click.

I'm stumped as to why the link works but the text doesn't. I had a CSS-only version working before where the labels were not containing the input and spans, but had to change that around due to wrapping issues.   Here is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oxd9hpf7/) and the code html/css/js below.  I've tried a few variations like toggling the checked attribute but no luck.

jQuery:

```
$("fieldset.radio label").click(function () {
    $("fieldset.radio label").removeClass("radioselect");
    $(this).addClass("radioselect");
});

$("fieldset.check label").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("checkselect")) {
        $(this).removeClass("checkselect");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("checkselect");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>Radio works:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
    <fieldset class="radio">
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="1"> <span>Here is option one</span>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="2"> <span>Here is option two</span>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="3"> <span>Here is option three</span>

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div>Checks do not:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
    <fieldset class="check">
        <div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""> <span>I have read the <a href="#">terms &amp; conditions</a>.</span>

                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""> <span>I want to receive cool news and promotions.</span>

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, a {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
div.fieldrow {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 10px;
}
form div.fieldrow > div, form div.fieldrow > fieldset > div {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
div.fieldrow > fieldset label {
    line-height: 1.7;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #3f6e74;
    background: rgba(3, 32, 38, 0.5);
}
fieldset input[type=checkbox], fieldset input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
fieldset label {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > input {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > span {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}
fieldset > div > div {
    position: relative;
}
fieldset > div > div > label:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 3px;
    background-color: #032026;
    border: 1px solid #76cddb;
}
fieldset.radio label:before {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
fieldset.radio > div > div > label.radioselect:before {
    background-color: #76CDDB;
}
fieldset.check > div > div > label.checkselect:before {
    content:"\2713";
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #76CDDB;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 8px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oax1pwe7/1/

Comment: Wow, that worked great!  Thanks so much!   I'm kicking myself for not having tried that but I guess it wasn't as obvious (to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `change` event instead of `click`. Also use `toggleClass` instead of first checking if the element have a class using `hasClass` and then adding/removing it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oxd9hpf7/4/)

```js
$("fieldset.radio label").change(function() {
  $("fieldset.radio label").removeClass("radioselect");
  $(this).addClass("radioselect");
});

$("fieldset.check label").change(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("checkselect");
});
```

```css
body,
a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
div.fieldrow {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 10px;
}
form div.fieldrow > div,
form div.fieldrow > fieldset > div {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
div.fieldrow > fieldset label {
  line-height: 1.7;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #3f6e74;
  background: rgba(3, 32, 38, 0.5);
}
fieldset input[type=checkbox],
fieldset input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
fieldset label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
fieldset > div > div {
  position: relative;
}
fieldset > div > div > label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: #032026;
  border: 1px solid #76cddb;
}
fieldset.radio label:before {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
fieldset.radio > div > div > label.radioselect:before {
  background-color: #76CDDB;
}
fieldset.check > div > div > label.checkselect:before {
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #76CDDB;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Radio works:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
  <fieldset class="radio">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="1"> <span>Here is option one</span>

        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="2"> <span>Here is option two</span>

        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="3"> <span>Here is option three</span>

        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div>Checks do not:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
  <fieldset class="check">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value=""> <span>I have read the <a href="#">terms &amp; conditions</a>.</span>

        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value=""> <span>I want to receive cool news and promotions.</span>

        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

---

If you can change the HTML structure, you don't need JS at all for checkbox.

1. Move the checkbox element out of the `label`
2. Add id to the checkbox and same as `for` attribute value to the corresponding `label`
3. Use `:checked` property and adjacent sibling CSS selector to set styles for the checked checkbox

```js
$("fieldset.radio label").change(function() {
  $("fieldset.radio label").removeClass("radioselect");
  $(this).addClass("radioselect");
});
```

```css
body,
a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
div.fieldrow {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.fieldrow > label {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 10px;
}
form div.fieldrow > div,
form div.fieldrow > fieldset > div {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
div.fieldrow > fieldset label {
  line-height: 1.7;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #3f6e74;
  background: rgba(3, 32, 38, 0.5);
}
fieldset input[type=checkbox],
fieldset input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
fieldset label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
fieldset > div > div > label > span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
fieldset > div > div {
  position: relative;
}
fieldset > div > div > label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 3px;
  background-color: #032026;
  border: 1px solid #76cddb;
}
fieldset.radio label:before {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
fieldset.radio > div > div > label.radioselect:before {
  background-color: #76CDDB;
}
fieldset.check > div > div >:checked + label:before {
  /* Use :checked and adjacent sibling properties here*/
  content: "\2713";
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #76CDDB;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Radio works:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
  <fieldset class="radio">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="1"> <span>Here is option one</span>

        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="2"> <span>Here is option two</span>

        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="3"> <span>Here is option three</span>

        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div>Checks do not:</div>
<div class="fieldrow">
  <fieldset class="check">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input id="1c" type="checkbox" value="">
        <!-- Move it out of label -->
        <label for="1c">
          <!-- Add for with the corresponding checkbox id -->
          <span>I have read the <a href="#">terms &amp; conditions</a>.</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="2c" type="checkbox" value="">
        <!-- Move it out of label -->
        <label for="2c">
          <!-- Add for with the corresponding checkbox id -->
          <span>I want to receive cool news and promotions.</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```